# How can i add another line under my RSS link?

Tags: css, sidebar, horizontal-line

How can I add the same blue line above my RSS link, below it with the same spacing? Im trying to space it out with the facebook badge.   http://jeffreydowellphotography.com/blog/

UPDATE:

Here is my html code. Can it be added in here somewhere?

```
<form action="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify" method="post" target="popupwindow" onsubmit="window.open('http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=Blog-JeffreyDowellPhotography', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');return true"><p>Subscribe via Email:</p><p><input type="text" style="width:140px" name="email"/></p><input type="hidden" value="Blog-JeffreyDowellPhotography" name="uri"/><input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US"/><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" style=" margin-bottom: 40px;"/></form>




<p><a Style="marging-left: 7;" href="feeds.feedburner.com/Blog-JeffreyDowellPhotography"; rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml"><img src="//feedburner.google.com/fb/images/pub/feed-icon16x16.png" alt="" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #E2E7F5;vertical-align:middle;border:0margin-top: 0;"/></a>&nbsp;<a href="feeds.feedburner.com/Blog-JeffreyDowellPhotography"; rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml">Subscribe via RSS</a></p>




<!-- Facebook Badge START --> <a Style="margin-top: 40px; margin-bottom:20px; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px; border-bottom: 2px solid #E2E7F5; href="https://www.facebook.com/JeffreyDowellPhotography" target="_TOP" title="Jeffrey Dowell Photography"> <img src="https://badge.facebook.com/badge/696174530397916.3512.386387771.png" style="border: 0px;" /> </a> <!-- Facebook Badge END -->
```

Comment: You will need to post your HTML markup so we can better see what element to style.

Comment: Also, posting links to your external site is generally frowned upon here at SO.

Comment: i didn't realize it was frowned upon, my apologies

Comment: No worries, just a heads up. If you want to show off something in working order, try pasting your code into http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
.sqs-block-content p {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #E2E7F5;
}
```

This will add the same style border to the bottom of the `<p>` element.

***UPDATE***

Add an `id` to the `<p>` tag and then apply similar CSS to it. Like so:

```
#your_id {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #E2E7F5;
}
```

Comment: this adds a line under every paragraph

Comment: You will need to add an `id` to the `<p>` tag and target it that way. See my update above.

Comment: i dont know the ID or how to make one.

Comment: Here is a good resource to learn more about `id`s as well as a lot of other questions you may have about CSS. http://www.cssbasics.com/css-ids/ Since you're just starting out, you'll probably be better off reading through the basics before posting here. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following styles to your `p` element that contains the RSS.

### CSS

```
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom:20px;
padding-top:20px;
padding-bottom:20px;
border-bottom: 2px solid #E2E7F5;
```

[image]

Comment: this adds a line under every paragraph too

Comment: If you just add the style to the specific paragraph (either with an in-line style or through an ID) that contains the RSS feed it shouldn't apply to every paragraph.

Comment: I dont know how to do this. Its a template base site from squarespace.com with lots of css that i have added in.

Comment: Try adding the styles I or Dryden suggested to your `<p>` element in your updated code.  Also a quick note.  I see a `marging-left: 7;` in your code, which has an extra `g`, so it should be `margin-left: 7;`     Try changing `<p>` to `<p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom:20px; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px; border-bottom: 2px solid #E2E7F5;">` to see if it helps any.  Or, like Dryden suggested, you can also change it to something like `<p id="rssPara">` and adding in your css: `#rssPara {border-bottom: 2px solid #E2E7F5;}`

Comment: that worked, thank you both. Can you make it centered? I added align:center but it didnt work.

Comment: What would you like centered, the RSS image and text?

Comment: Look what I've done here and see if it helps.  Note that the background colors I used are only for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/shaunp/PDPXc/